# how do I enforce this type checking? The code allows any type to be returned or passed

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm trying to use type hints. My tests so far allow defining type hints but they do not seem to be enforced.

```
from typing import Type,TypeVar

MyType=TypeVar("MyType",bound="my")

class my:
    @staticmethod
    def factory(test) -> MyType:
        if test==1:
                return my(1)
        if test==2:
                return Exception("what am I")
        return None
    def __init__(self,thevar):
        self.test=thevar
    def typecheck(var: MyType):
        print("function called with type %s" % type(var))

myclass=my("")
for test in range(0,3):
    thevar=my.factory(test)
    print ("My type is %s" % type(thevar))
    my.typecheck(thevar)
```

I am expecting errors to be raised when the wrong type is passed or returned.
Except perhaps for when a None is returned instead of a class

Comment: Python does not have runtime static type checking. Type annotations are only evaluated offline using something like `mypy`. What is your expected output and what is it you're getting?

Comment: "runtime static type checking" is somewhat of an oxymoron. Static type checking applies to the code, not its runtime semantics.

Comment: You *raise* an exception, you don't return them. `factory` should probably never return `None`.

Comment: True, a bit of inaccurate language on my part. Static type checking by definition is before runtime, and rather somewhere in the compile phase. python does not need to be compiled because it is interpreted, and therefore the whole concept is a bit muddy. Python does however do type checking at runtime to prevent invalid operations on data (ie: casting an int to a float before division.)

Comment: So there's no point in using typechecking to catch bugs?

Comment: You use a tool like mypy to catch bugs, some IDE's may even be beginning to integrate mypy directly into their editors. It's not altogether different from code [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) (like pylint or pyflakes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aaron mentioned, this is usually done with another tool (mypy), rather than the python interpreter.

To install mypy ([from the docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)):

```
$ python3 -m pip install mypy
```

Then, to type check your code with mypy:

```
$ mypy program.py
```